# mysqli & bound statements, 2031: No data for parameters in statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here is my code, that isn't working, don't know why:

```
$sql = `INSERT INTO `_translations` (id, module, item_id, name_id, output, language) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE output = ?`
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, $sql);
$params = array($stmt, $types);
foreach($array as $k=>&$v){
    $params[] =& $v;
}
// this call is update call, therefore parameters are merged
if($update && $_update) $params = array_merge($params, $_update);
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $params); # i think the problem is in this line..
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    if($this->transaction){ $this->affected++; }
    else{ $this->affected = 1; }
}else{ 
    $error = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt); 
    $errno = mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt);
    die("{$sql}<br/><pre>".var_export($params, true)."</pre><br/>{$errno}: {$error}");
}
```

`die()` results in:

```
INSERT INTO `_translations` (id, module, item_id, name_id, output, language) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE output = ?
array (
  0 => 
  mysqli_stmt::__set_state(array(
     'affected_rows' => NULL,
     'insert_id' => NULL,
     'num_rows' => NULL,
     'param_count' => NULL,
     'field_count' => NULL,
     'errno' => NULL,
     'error' => NULL,
     'sqlstate' => NULL,
     'id' => NULL,
  )),
  1 => 'isissss',
  2 => '',
  3 => 'seo',
  4 => '',
  5 => 'keywords',
  6 => 'tesoutput',
  7 => 'en',
  8 => 'tesoutput',
)

2031: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
```

Well, type count equals parameters and everything should be working fine, but it isn't. Since this same function runs for simple inserts, I know it works... If more data is needed from my side, feel free to ask.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE #1:**
Here are $array, $types and $update print outs.
P.S. There's a chain before each of all these 3 variables are set, but they contain exactly what's needed!

```
// $array
array(6) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["module"]=>
  string(3) "seo"
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["name_id"]=>
  string(8) "keywords"
  ["output"]=>
  string(9) "tesoutput"
  ["language"]=>
  string(2) "en"
}
// $types
string(7) "isissss"
// $update
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "tesoutput"
}
```

I have already thought that the problem could be in `$types` string not maching `$array` value types, because all values are strings there. I'm not sure, though, because when inserting without update, it works, even if those are strings.

**UPDATE #2:**
It looks like it's a version related bug, driver bug - http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43568 ... Anyone has managed to get this to work `> 5.2` with `mysqlnd`? And, yes, here on localhost I'm running `5.2.6` with default `mysql` driver, where on production server, PHP is running version `5.3.5` with `mysqlnd`.

Comment: @Tom: Line 3-4: where does `$types`/`$array` come from/look like?

Comment: Actually, the biggest problem here is, that I cannot even find a proper description why `2031: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement` occurs and in what cases it occurs. Any help is appreciated and will be rewarded!

Comment: Why all the references/pointers?? You don't even use them later on...

Comment: @Rudie, because bound parameters cannot be constant values, therefore you have to use references. See `PHP` bug link and my answer to question.

Comment: Did you add the bounty *after* solving it yourself? Or is there still something to answer?

Comment: @mario, I added bounty tad before solving the question. But anyone who's willing to contribute, can answer and if I'll find something interesting in answer, bounty will be rewarded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more research on http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43568, I've managed to fix the problem by replacing:

```
foreach($array as $k=>&$v){
    $params[] =& $v;
}
if($update && $_update) $params = array_merge($params, $_update); # this is the actual line, that I've replaced
```

with:

```
// did a little housekeeping too
foreach($array as $k=>&$v) $params[] =& $v;
if($update && $_update) foreach($_update as $kk => $vv) $params[] =& $v; # instead of merging, I'm populating values the hard way.
```

Huh, interesting how 5.2 allows constant value binding, and 5.3 doesn't. Anyways, I'm happy I've resolved this, and I hope it will help others in future.

This actually explains why `insert` did work regardless of version... those values were getting populated with reference variables from the beggining.